# Visual Studio 2022 Community: Stuck with C# language version 7.3?

Tags: c#

Trying to use sample code from the book "Learn C# programming..." by Bancila and Sharma.
When I try to build the project, I get error messages saying that certain features are not available in C# 7.3, and that I should upgrade to C# 9.0 resp. 10.0.
However, there is no way to change the language version. When I go to Project Properties/Build/Advanced, the language version shows frozen. Also, adding the line "`<LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>`" in the .csprog file seems to have no effect.
Can somebody help or at least explain?
Thanks!

I added the line "`<LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>`" in the .csprog file. But the problem remains.

Comment: What .NET version are you using? Is it .NET Framework or .NET (Core)?

Comment: Use the proper project template to get started.  Right now you use one that has ".NET Framework" in its name.  It targets the legacy version of .NET, version 4.8 typically, which can't support C# higher than 7.3.  Pick one that has ".NET" in its name and you can select version 5 and up, which do support higher C# versions.

Answer (score 2):

The C# version depends on the .NET / .NET Framework version you are using.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: this doesn't address the OP question; installing the latest .NET version doesn't solve this issue

Comment: @gadget00 maybe you don't understand the OP's question because this absolutely solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download the relevant SDk to have access to newer versions of C#.

For C# 9, you need the .NET 5 SDK.

You can find it here:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

Comment: this doesn't address the OP question; installing the latest .NET version doesn't solve this issue

Comment: The SDK will provide the newer C# versions...

Answer (score 0):

The book is targeted for C# 8 i.e. net core 3, so I would recommend just creating a project for .Net 6 or 7. These should be fully backward compatible with .net Core 3. In the visual studio installer you can select what specific .Net versions you want to include support for. I would expect .Net 6 to be installed by default, but it is easy to check.